# How can I sync two local directories?

Tags: files, rsync, file-management

I have two backup directories (dir1 and 2) on two different (local) HDDs and I want to create one of them. How can I really sync their contents so that both directories will have the same contents?

Comment: Do you want to do a one-way sync, or do you need to update the files both ways?

Comment: You seem to know one correct command (`rsync`). What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Kusalananda a one-way sync is enough for now because i want to delete dir1, but a two-way sync would be useful later.

Comment: @roaima I only tried `rsync -rtvu dir1 dir2/` as mentioned [here](http://www.jveweb.net/en/archives/2010/11/synchronizing-folders-with-rsync.html#jveweb_en_014_05) without `--delete`. Now i see that the problem was the missing '/' from the end of 'dir1'.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To sync the contents of dir1 to dir2 on the same system, type:

```
rsync -av --progress --delete dir1/ dir2
```

> `-a`, `--archive`
>           archive mode
>
> `--delete`
>           delete extraneous files from dest dirs
>
> `-v`, `--verbose`
>           Verbose mode (increase verbosity)
>
> `--progress`
>           show progress during transfer

<sup>— from [rsync(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rsync.1.html)</sup>

Note : The `/` after dir1 is necessary to mean "the contents of dir1". 
Without the trailing slash, would place dir1, including the directory, within dir2. This would create a hierarchy that looks like:

```
…/dir2/dir1/[files]
```