# A question about using rsync to sync two folders

Tags: rsync

I have looked this topic up and found two answers:

[How can I sync two local directories?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/392536/how-can-i-sync-two-local-directories)

[How to sync two folders with command line tools?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203846/how-to-sync-two-folders-with-command-line-tools)

The interesting thing is, the two commands for rsync, one with and another without the `-u` option made a big difference:

```
rsync -av --progress --delete "/folder/" "/somewhere/folder"
```

vs

```
rsync -avu --progress --delete "/folder/" "/somewhere/folder"
```

The one with the `-u` option only copied the files names, the actual size is 0B.

Why is that happening? Shouldn't it also copy the actual bits too?~~

New question that is more specific: [How does the rsync -u option help syncing two folders?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/693773/how-does-the-rsync-u-option-help-syncing-two-folders)

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this on my machine.  Can you try again (with a clean destination) and with `-i` added?  Is there a difference in the output with and without `-u`?  (Can add it to the question).

Comment: No there is not a difference, I will investigate this issue some more than update the question.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `rsync` explains that `-u` (`--update`) only updates files that are not newer on the destination. See `man rsync`.

If your files on the source are not newer than the corresponding files on the destination no changes will be made - even if the files have differences.

Comment: There is a change, the new stuff, folders and files get copied over, but only the name and not the actual bits.