# How does the rsync -u option help syncing two folders?

Tags: rsync

I want folder `source` and folder `destination` to be synced, in which all changes in `source` are to be reflected to destination.

In this case, I would be using the rsync command like so:

```
rsync -av --progress --delete "/source/" "/destination"
```

With a / for source to specify its contents and without / for destination.

Now, do I have to use the `-u` option in order to the destination to update if source has a newer modified time? Or is `-av` already enough?

And would I need the `-i` option at all? Thank you!

> -u, --update
> This forces rsync to skip any files which exist on the destination and have a modified  time  that
> is  newer than the source file.  (If an existing destination file has a modification time equal to
> the source file’s, it will be updated if the sizes are different.)
> Note that this does not affect the copying of symlinks or other special files.  Also, a difference
> of  file format between the sender and receiver is always considered to be important enough for an
> update, no matter what date is on the objects.  In other words, if  the  source  has  a  directory
> where the destination has a file, the transfer would occur regardless of the timestamps.
> This  option  is a transfer rule, not an exclude, so it doesn’t affect the data that goes into the
> file-lists, and thus it doesn’t affect deletions.  It just limits  the  files  that  the  receiver
> requests to be transferred.

> --delete
> This tells rsync to delete extraneous files from the receiving  side  (ones  that  aren’t  on  the
> sending  side),  but  only  for  the directories that are being synchronized.  You must have asked
> rsync to send the whole directory (e.g.  "dir"  or  "dir/")  without  using  a  wildcard  for  the
> directory’s  contents  (e.g.  "dir/*")  since the wildcard is expanded by the shell and rsync thus
> gets a request to transfer individual files, not the files’  parent  directory.   Files  that  are
> excluded   from   the   transfer  are  also  excluded  from  being  deleted  unless  you  use  the
> --delete-excluded option or mark the  rules  as  only  matching  on  the  sending  side  (see  the
> include/exclude modifiers in the FILTER RULES section).
> Prior  to rsync 2.6.7, this option would have no effect unless --recursive was enabled.  Beginning
> with 2.6.7, deletions will also occur when --dirs (-d) is enabled, but only for directories  whose
> contents are being copied.
> This option can be dangerous if used incorrectly!  It is a very good idea to first try a run using
> the --dry-run option (-n) to see what files are going to be deleted.
> If the sending side detects any I/O errors, then the deletion of any files at the destination will
> be  automatically  disabled. This is to prevent temporary filesystem failures (such as NFS errors)
> on the sending side from causing a massive deletion of files on the destination.  You can override
> this with the --ignore-errors option.
> The  --delete  option  may  be combined with one of the --delete-WHEN options without conflict, as
> well as --delete-excluded.  However, if none of the --delete-WHEN  options  are  specified,  rsync
> will  choose  the  --delete-during  algorithm  when  talking  to  rsync  3.0.0  or  newer, and the
> --delete-before  algorithm  when  talking  to  an  older  rsync.   See  also  --delete-delay   and
> --delete-after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, do I have to use the `-u` option in order to the destination to update if source has a newer modified time?

No, that's already the case.  What `-u` does is to *prevent* changes happening if the destination is newer.  Without `-u`, such files will be updated to the version on the source (which could be older).

> And would I need the -i option at all?

`-i` (like `--progress`) doesn't affect the sync behavior, just the output that is displayed.  It just shows additional information about each file selected.

Comment: Yeah - the `-u` option is rather strange methinks... but it surely does come in handy at times. On my macOS (source), I use `rsync` as a file backup using a NAS as the destination. One of the folders on my Mac has a bunch of pictures. It was driving me crazy that there was this one file on the NAS whose mod time was apparently being changed every time it was checked by `rsync`, and therefore **always** showed up in the (`-i`) listing. Adding the `-u` option stopped that.

Answer (score 0):

You've already got an excellent, accepted answer; this answer serves as an embellishment to that answer:

> do I have to use the -u option in order [for]<s>to</s> the destination to update if source has a newer modified time? Or is -av already enough?

The `-u` option is a bit *odd* IMHO; odd in the sense that it (apparently) prevents `rsync` from updating the source file's *modification time* if it happens to be newer on the source. This can be useful in some situations.

> And would I need the -i option at all?

IMO, the `-i` (*aka* `--itemize-changes`) option can be *extremely* useful in troubleshooting issues/questions that always arise in the use of `rsync`. One issue with the use of this option is described in `man rsync` as follows:

> ... a cryptic output that is 11 letters long. The general format is like the string YXcstpoguax

... with ***cryptic*** being the operative word. However, I found the following table which **helps** a bit. I copy & paste this table as a gigantic *`# comment`* into shell scripts that call `rsync` :

```
# decode --itemize-changes output:
#
# YXcstpoguax  path/to/file
# |||||||||||
# `----------- "Y" - the type of update being done::
#  ||||||||||   < : file is being transferred to the remote host (sent).
#  ||||||||||   > : file is being transferred to the local host (received).
#  ||||||||||   c: local change/creation for the item, such as:
#  ||||||||||      - the creation of a directory
#  ||||||||||      - the changing of a symlink,
#  ||||||||||      - etc.
#  ||||||||||   h: the item is a hard link to another item (requires --hard-links).
#  ||||||||||   .: the item is not being updated (though it might have attributes that are being modified).
#  ||||||||||   *: means that the rest of the itemized-output area contains a message (e.g. "deleting").
#  ||||||||||
#  `---------- "X" - the file type:
#   |||||||||   f for a file,
#   |||||||||   d for a directory,
#   |||||||||   L for a symlink,
#   |||||||||   D for a device,
#   |||||||||   S for a special file (e.g. named sockets and fifos).
#   |||||||||
#   `--------- c: different checksum (for regular files)
#    ||||||||     changed value (for symlink, device, and special file)
#    `-------- s: Size is different
#     `------- t: Modification time is different; T: time set to transfer time
#      `------ p: Permission are different
#       `----- o: Owner is different
#        `---- g: Group is different
#         `--- u: reserved for future use
#          `-- a: The ACL information changed
#           `- x: extended attribute changed
```

For example, consider the following output line produced by using the `-i` option:

```
>f..t....... Desktop/pics/SomePicture.jpg
```

Decoded as:

- `>` : file is being transferred to the local host (received)
- `f` : a file is being transferred
- `t` : Modification time is different